# Get-VM for a hyper-v , what are the differecnes between VMName & Name

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I want to get a list of VMS for a Hyper-V server, so I run the following command , to get the VMs details inside hyper-v server named "hyperV01":-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName hyperV01.customerABC.local -Credential hyperV01\Administrator {Get-VM}
```

now i got two fields regarding the VM name; VMName & Name, as follow:-

```
VMName                      : VMPC

Name                        : VMPC
```

I have 2 questions regarding this :-

1. Can anyone advice what are the differences between these 2 fields (VMName & Name), as in my case these 2 fields appears to have exact same value for each VM ?
2. Can i get the fully qualified name for the VM such as `VMPC.domainname.local` or it is something I need to configure on the VM in a way or another  ?

Comment: Hey John John you did ask that question over at Microsoft Q&A and got an answer ([differecnes-between-vmname-name](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8a135998-b214-4f21-85b4-cae7fc8b93f5/differecnes-between-vmname-name-when-i-run-getvm-for-a-hyperv-server)) Posting here for reference: VMname is an alias to Name.